# node.js tcp line receiver implementation for big size data

Tags: node.js, tcp, stream

I am trying to write a new line separated TCP client that should be able to receive big size data.
The characteristic of the incoming data to be received are,

Data are new line separated.
Data are also continuously coming from some server. 
some times data multiple new line separated small size and big size data as burst. But they are very well new line separated.

I am trying to write a node.js program for the same. but it is not working.
I have tried the ..

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

I am looking to enhance the above program.

some times it dumps incomplete data and some times multiple new line separated data at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee about how much data (except that there will be at least 1 byte) you will receive in a 'data' event handler. You will have to buffer the data yourself and search for newline manually and cut where appropriate. Something like this:

```
var buffer = '';
client.on('data', function(data) {
  var prev = 0, next;
  data = data.toString('utf8'); // assuming utf8 data...
  while ((next = data.indexOf('\n', prev)) > -1) {
    buffer += data.substring(prev, next);

    // do something with `buffer` here ...
    console.log('got whole message: ' + buffer);

    buffer = '';
    prev = next + 1;
  }
  buffer += data.substring(prev);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a `net.Socket` is a Readable stream, you can use the [`event-stream` module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/event-stream) for this. It contains the `.split()` function that ensures that each line is a chunk:

```
client.pipe(es.split())
.pipe(es.map(function (data, cb) {
    console.log('Got the following message:', data);
    cb(null)
});
```